# Why does an InputStream initialized with a String stay open outside a try-with-resources?

Tags: java, inputstream, try-with-resources

I noticed that this throws an `IOException` as expected, due to the stream being auto-closed:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("pom.xml"))) {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
}

bufferedReader.readLine();
```

whereas when the `InputStream` is initialized with a `String`, it does not:

```
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;

try (InputStream inputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream("test")) {
    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
}

bufferedInputStream.read();
```

Both the `BufferedReader` and the `BufferedInputStream` are initialized with an object that is closed outside the brackets.  Is it related to the way an `InputStream` handles a `String` internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the [answer provided by fge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906315/438154), the `InputStream` returned by `IOUtils#toInputStream("test")` is a `ByteArrayInputStream` whose [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#close--) method is a no-op.

> Closing a `ByteArrayInputStream` has no effect. The methods in this
>   class can be called after the stream has been closed without
>   generating an `IOException`.

The `FileReader` internally maintains a handle to the file. That handle becomes invalid once you invoke `close` on the `FileReader` and the wrapping `BufferedReader` will then fail to use it. This doesn't happen with the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding something.

The only resources which are automatically closed are the ones *within the initial parens*:

```
try (
    final R r1 = ...;
) {
    final R r2 = ...;
} // at this point, r1 is closed for you; r2 is NOT
```

Note that you can declare more than one resource in the initial parens as well.

Comment: I understand that but I'm asking why the BufferedInputStream but not the BufferedReader lives on with an object that is auto-closed.

Comment: See the answer by @SotiriosDelimanolis as to why. But anyway, closing resources is always the thing to do in any case.